# How can I retrieve folder structure in Windows?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, raid, data-recovery, hard-drive-recovery

I had a Windows 10 installation on a 4 SSDs RAID 0 array which I lost 3 days ago. I have rebuilt the array and reinstalled Windows right after the incident.

The thing is that I had some files and folders in the Desktop folder of the previous installation which I know that I have lost forever. By the way, I have tried numerous data recovery programs.

The problem is that I cannot even remember what files and folders were there to estimate the importance of the data I lost.

Is there any file that stores the folder structure in Windows 10 or any trick to retrieve this structure in general (maybe some metadata)?

If such data is stored somewhere I thought it might be easier to retrieve.

Also, any suggestions of software that can do this are welcome.

Comment: No - any metadata that might have existed.will have gone with the RAID rebuild. And that is the consequence for using RAID0. That you immediately rebuilt another RAID0 device shows you don't care about your data, so why should we?

Comment: @davidgo The truth is I was not sure so I thought it should be possible to restore data after reinstalling. But I would like to ask you a question. Let's say that I have a RAID 0 array with some stripe size. If I rebuild it without tampering without writing data or installing anything on the drives will the data still be lost, and does it matter whether I keep or change the stripe size?

Comment: I can't really answer these questions, as I doubt I would ever use RAID0 - I expect it will depend on your RAID controller/Software RAID setup. Of-course If you replaced or format any disks you immediately loose.  Once you reinstall, you overwrite pretty much  any data that could once have been in tact.  I note that rebuild and recreate different meanings, and I assume you mean recreate.  Rebuilding is done each time the RAID is started (at least on Linux software RAID)

Comment: Your data was already in critical danger after the original RAID failed. Recovery at that point was already almost impossible. As soon as you rebuilt & re-installed, you removed the 'almost'. This is what we have backups for.

Comment: @Tetsujin I understand your points but I have a question. When you are claiming that even before rebuilding the array it would be almost impossible, are you talking from your own experience i.e. have you ever tried to restore files after some RAID 0 failure? I'm saying that since there are programs like EaseUS or Stellar Phoenix that specifically claim they can restore data in such cases.

Comment: I've never managed to restore from a broken RAID0, although I never tried too hard. I just rebuilt & restored from backup. I used to use RAID0s for speed, back when we only had small spinning disks on SCSI; but would never trust them for stability/reliability, even then.